# facebook php skd api setting proper permissions to access user data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I'm trying to use php to access and collect basic information on-

> users name, gender, birthday, age_range etc.

but for some reason I can only get the name and gender to work and I get an `Undefined index:` with `birthday` and `age_range`.

Can someone help me figure this out? I am new to Facebook Graph API and trying to modify the given code they gave for logging. I think I don't need an access token yet because I'm trying to get the initial permissions when they log into the site.

```
<?php
include('src\facebook.php');

//$scope = 'username,age_range,birthday,gender';

$config = array(
      'appId'              => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      'secret'             => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      'fileUpload'         => false, 
      'allowSignedRequest' => false 
    );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($user_id) {
      try {
            //$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET', array('scope' => 'user_birthday,gender,age_range,name,likes'));
            echo "Name: " .     $user_profile['name'];
            echo " Gender: " . $user_profile['gender'];
            echo " DOB: " .    $user_profile['birthday'];
            echo " Age_Range: " .    $user_profile['age_range'];
      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
            echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
            error_log($e->getType());
            error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {
      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
    }
  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Also could someone explain to how to get user likes, I know I have to specify user permission using the Facebook->api(me/like) but then how do I access the array? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow **only the official docs** to avoid such mistakes-

1. You are adding the permissions scope into the wrong place.
2. You are using the wrong permissions: `gender,age_range,name,likes` - these are not valid permissions!

   Permissions that you require are: `user_likes` (for likes), `user_birthday`(for birthday); rest are the part of the basic(default) permissions only!

   The age range field is also included in the public profile- for anyone who installs your app.

You have to add the `scope` parameter while using the **login code**: [getLoginUrl()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/).

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'user_likes, user_birthday'
);
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

After the user successfully grants the permissions, you'll get the required things!